# Want to keep original values when using if_else() in mutate() if condition isn't met

Tags: r, if-statement, dplyr

I've got the below line of code where I'm trying to change the fpts value in the dataframe for different positions (QB, RB, WR, TE) but keep them the same for the other two positions (DST, K). If I run this, the QB, RB, WR, TE position values change for fpts, but the DST and K fpts change to 0. Any idea why that's happening? There are already values in the fpts column for all of the positions, but I just want to change the fpts value for those four positions I mentioned.

```
library(tidyverse)
library(dplyr)

projections <-read_csv("https://raw.githubusercontent.com/samhoppen/2020_FF_Analysis/master/Functions/Projections.csv")

projections <- projections %>% 
     mutate(fpts = (if(position == "QB" || position == "RB" || position == "WR" || position == "TE"){
                             (pass_yds * 0.1) +
                                 (pass_tds * 4) +
                                 (pass_ints * -2) +
                                 (rush_yds * 0.1) +
                                 (rush_tds * 6) + 
                                 (fl * -2) +
                                 (rec_rec * 1) +
                                 (rec_yds * 0.1) +
                                 (rec_tds * 6)}
              else{fpts}))
```

Comment: `mutate(fpts = if_else(some & (long | conditional), new_value, fpts))` preserves its original value if the conditional is not true.

Comment: BTW, `if_else(position %in% c("QB", "RB", "WR", "TE"), (lots_of_math), fpts)`

Answer (score 1):

We can use `case_when/ifelse` instead of `if/else` as `if/else` is not vectorized i.e it expects a single element and not the whole columns

```
library(dplyr)
projections %>%
    mutate(fpts = case_when(position %in% c('QB', 'RB', 'WR', 'TE')~ 
     (pass_yds * 0.1) +
                             (pass_tds * 4) +
                             (pass_ints * -2) +
                             (rush_yds * 0.1) +
                             (rush_tds * 6) + 
                             (fl * -2) +
                             (rec_rec * 1) +
                             (rec_yds * 0.1) +
                             (rec_tds * 6), TRUE ~ fpts))
# A tibble: 790 x 16
#   player team  position pass_att pass_cmp pass_yds pass_tds pass_ints rush_att rush_yds rush_tds    fl  fpts
#   <chr>  <chr> <chr>       <dbl>    <dbl>    <dbl>    <dbl>     <dbl>    <dbl>    <dbl>    <dbl> <dbl> <dbl>
# 1 Lamar… BAL   QB           465.     297.    3465.     29.8      11.9    156.     968.       5.5   4.1  564.
# 2 Patri… KC    QB           558.     361     4453.     33.3       9.8     72.3    353.       3.7   3.5  609.
# 3 Dak P… DAL   QB           558.     363     4463.     28.6      12.4     53.4    269.       3.8   3.3  579.
# 4 Desha… HOU   QB           515.     339.    3997.     25.3      14.8     94.8    509.       5.1   3.7  545.
# 5 Russe… SEA   QB           478.     312     3842.     29.2       8.5     77.7    414.       2.5   2.9  535.
# 6 Kyler… ARI   QB           542.     349.    3733.     24.9      15.1     94.9    525        3.7   2.7  512.
# 7 Josh … BUF   QB           510.     299.    3479.     20.1      13.8    106.     612.       7.2   5.2  495.
# 8 Tom B… TB    QB           559      347.    4447.     29.3      11.8     25.7     32.3      1.8   2.6  547.
# 9 Matt … ATL   QB           621.     407.    4604.     27.6      14.9     33      128.       1     4.6  551.
#10 Drew … NO    QB           517.     365.    3889      30.5       9.5     19.7     21.7      1.7   1.8  501.
# … with 780 more rows, and 3 more variables: rec_rec <dbl>, rec_yds <dbl>, rec_tds <dbl>
```

Answer (score 0):

This will only work over a span of 2 years of data, but it might give you some ideas

```
library(dplyr)
library(lubridate)
library(data.table)

setDT(df)


df <- df[Year == max(df$Year) | Year == max(df$Year)-1] # limit dataset to last 2 years
year <- unique(df$Year)

coef <- list(0,1)
week.count <- list()
df$week.no <- 0

for (i in year) {
        j <- i-min(df$Year)+1
        weeks <- lubridate::week(df[Year == i]$Date)
        week.count[[j]] <- max(weeks)
        add <- coef[[j]]*week.count[[max(j-1,1)]]
        df <- df %>% 
                 mutate(week.no = case_when(df$Year == i ~ week(df$Date) + add,
                                            df$Year != i ~ week.no))
}
```

I'm new to this so open to any constructive criticism :)